# how to add action bar in bottom navigation in Nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

i'm trying to add an action drawer or an action bar to bottom navigation, any ideas how?
im using typescript

i read the nativescript docs and dont seem to find anym information about it.

please help

here is my code below:

```
   <BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0">


<TabStrip>
    <TabStripItem>
        <Label text="Home"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf015;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

    <TabStripItem class="special">
        <Label text="Profile"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
</TabStrip>


<TabContentItem>

        <StackLayout>

        <VideoPlayer:Video id="nativeVideoPlayer"
        controls="true" loop="true" autoplay="true" Height="1000" scaleY="1.2"
        src="~/Videos/v2.mp4" />



    </StackLayout>

</TabContentItem>

<TabContentItem class="pp">



  <StackLayout>

    <Image src="font://&#xf2bd;" class="fasl t-36l"></Image>
     <Label text="Sign up for an account" class="align1"/>
    <Button text="Sign up" tap="navigateToFeatured" class="signupcolor"/>

  </StackLayout>




</TabContentItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use "Nesting Lateral in Forward Navigation" pattern.
Use a Frame as a root view, and have a main page for it. Inside this page, add your action bar and BottomNavigation itself. That's right, BottomNavigation can also be nested inside pages.

For more information, you can take a look at the docs: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/nested-navigation